# Generated link from QR code should be directed through browser

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I have already created a QR scanner android application. What I need is that if I scan a QR code and if it generates a link, so the app should automatically open that link through the browser.
Any help will be appreciated. Thank You!!

Comment: show us some of your code. where it goes wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the callback of QR code generated

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

To open that link in browser

As for the missing "http://" I'd just do something like this:

```
if (!url.startsWith("http://") && !url.startsWith("https://"))
url = "http://" + url;
```

To validate the URL

```
URLUtil.isValidUrl(url)
```

Comment: But I have a problem rit now. When i am directed to the browser and comes back to my application on pressing the back button, the camera of the qr code scanner is not open, that is it is full dark.

Comment: Its about the surfaceview . Intitalize that surface view in onresume

Comment: It s about the surfaceview issue , put your code and i will try

Comment: I solved the issue. I restarted the activity when I go back from browser to my app. Thanks for the previous solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already implemented a "**QR scanner**" then check, there must be a callback method where you receive the returned text from the "**Scanner**".

Inside that callback method, fire an intent to open the browser with a specific url like shown below:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url)); // here ulr is the one that you get from scanner
startActivity(i);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This is leading to crash. The code is working....you can see it above this.

Answer (score 0):

Down below is my QR scanner code :

```
public class VehicleReaderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler  {

private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTitle("SCAN QR CODE");
    mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
    setContentView(mScannerView);
    mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
    mScannerView.startCamera();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mScannerView.stopCamera();
}

@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    // Do anything with result here
    Log.w("handleResult", result.getText());

    // Now direct the generated link to the browser //
    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://" + result.getText()));
    startActivity(browserIntent);

    //Resume scanning
    //mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
}
}
```